# Using utf8 strings in C

Tags: c++, c, string, utf-8, air

I'm writing a native extension to Adobe AIR in C. The code should be ported to other platforms later.
In my function on C side I'm getting a string from air like this

```c
uint32_t len;
const uint8_t * str = 0;
if( FRE_OK == FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) )
{
    //Here i need to pass a string as an argument to other function
    printf("Got string %s", str); //Showing weird letters instead of str
}
```

FREGetObjectAsUTF8 returns a UTF8 encoded string which should be represented as const uint8_t. I'm working in MacOS and XCode and uint8_t is defined as unsigned char. The problem is in a bunch of c code which expects a simple char* as argument. I don't need any letters from unicode and I'm using only latin letters and digits.

I've tried to cast a type with no luck. As example

```c
char buffer[512];
sprintf(buffer, "%s", (char*)str); //Same weird letters here
```

But if I iterate over string I'm getting correct value

```c
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    printf("%s", str[i]); // Normal value
```

So mu question is: How could I pass a utf8 string to a function that expects a simple signed char?
In a fact I could try to create functions in c++ and use C part with "extern" but pure C solution will be more preferable.

I'm passing string "initapp" from air and if I return it back to runtime it shows me correct value "initapp". In my C code I'm trying to pass it in function which expects char* as an argument

```
FREObject initApp(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    uint32_t len;
    const uint8_t * str = 0;
    if( FRE_OK == FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) )
    {
        /*
        I have about 40 functions and most of them working with ASCII strings
        */
        executeCommand( (const char*)str );
        FREObject result;
        FRENewObjectFromUTF8(len, str, &result);
        return result; //It's ok. Correct string
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But in my function instead of "initapp" I'm getting various weird letters(different each time) like trying to output some part of image or incorrect variable.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the code sample really represents your code? The `sprintf` seems fine. However, the `printf` that you say works can't possibly work - you give it a single character and use `%s`, which should crash, UTF-8 or not.

Comment: Why use uint8_t in the first place? Anyway, what weird letters do you get? And you say "I don't need Unicode and i'm using only latin", but Latin is part of Unicode, so you already are using it!

Comment: UTF8 string comes from FREGetObjectAsUTF8 fucntion which is part of air framework. Yes i know what latin is the part of unicode. Weird letters like printing some garbage from memory

Comment: Oh, unless I'm mistaken, after you call FREGetObjectAsUTF8, `str` points to a buffer under the control of Flash. Best copy the result to a string of your own immediately after the call before continuing.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've tried to sprintf or strncpy but each time there was a garbage instead of my value. I've updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X generally expects simple char* strings to be UTF-8 anyway, so you should be getting correct results with the code you showed.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s", (char*)str);
```

If code like the following prints out numeric values indicating a valid UTF-8 string:

```
if( FRE_OK == FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) ) {
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        printf("0x%02X ", str[i]);

    FREObject result;
    FRENewObjectFromUTF8(len, str, &result);
}
```

And replacing the printf loop with calls to your own functions results in garbage:

```
if( FRE_OK == FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &len, &str) ) {
    executeCommand( (const char*)str );

    FREObject result;
    FRENewObjectFromUTF8(len, str, &result);
}
```

there is most likely a problem with executeCommand().

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm agreed i should be getting correct results but i don't. In a fact i'm getting some weird letters instead of my string. It's like trying to output some garbage from memory. But variable is correctly initialized and have correct length.

Comment: @icewind post more details on exactly what text output you're seeing and what numeric values the string consists of.

Answer (score 1):

> How could i pass a utf8 string to a function that expects a simple signed char?

Two ways to do it:

1. Simply cast it into const char*. utf8 string is "compatible" with const char string in a sense that ascii-only C string will be identical utf8 string that contains only Ascii characters, and utf8-string with non-ascii character will contain no zeroes in the middle. However, if you use this method, any character that is not part of ASCII will turn into unreadable sequence of chracters. Of course, if C function expects something like file path to open file, this won't work.
2. Use OS-specific text functions that allow you to change codepage and re-encode utf8-string into whatever 8-bit code page your system is using. However, by using this method, characters that are not part of system codepage will be "lost" - they'll be turned into some "default" character like '?' or "question mark in a square". So something like "study the 片仮名" will becmoe "study the ???". Alternatively, instead of OS function, you could try using something like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html#iconv-Examples), but this won't fix "characters not in codepage" problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using only ASCII characters in my code and i knew what utf8 string is compatible with char but simple type casting to char give me no results.  That's very strange.